# CRUD using .net core in Vs 2015

Tags: .net-core

I must create a project using .NET Core. I not experience about it. Can you help to create a basic CRUD using .NET Core? I have installed .NET Core and vs 2015.

This a description about my test:

1. You are to build a RESTful API with .NET Core Platform (https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform)
2. (BackEnd) Your Application must include a basic

   - Create (Adding a new Model)
   - Read

     - Index (Get a list of Models)
     - Detail (Get a Model by ID)
   - Update (Update an existing Model)
   - Delete (Delete a Model)
3. (FrontEnd) Your Application must utilise all of the above BackEnd methods

Comment: The same way as the full .NET Framework. EF and Dapper definitely work in .NET Core, most ADO.NET classes are available in .NET Core 2.0. Perhaps you should explain what you mean by `basic CRUD`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be many data access examples on the internet if you search e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db